# Bind jQuery hover event to multiple DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've an unordered list of elements and I want to bind hover event to each of these elements. The HTML structure is as follows :

```
<ul>
  <li id="url_1">item 1</li>
  <li id="url_2">item 2</li>
</ul>
```

I figured using a for-loop would be the best way to do it. So my jQuery code is as follows:

```
for(i=1;i<=2;i++){
   $("li#url_"+i).hover(function () { /* do something on mouseenter */}, function () { /* do something on mouseleave */ }); }
```

This should bind the hover event to li#url_1 & li#url_2. But it is not working!

Can you please suggest the right (and more efficient) way to do this?

Cheers,
Kartik Rao

Comment: works?  http://www.jsfiddle.net/nQzCt/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, don't forget to put your jQuery code inside a `$(document).ready(function {        })` block, so it would perform only the DOM is loaded.

Second, why not assign an `ID`, or `class`, or whatever what will help you access that `UL` element in the top, and then do this:

```
$("ul#yourId > li").hover(function() { ............. }, function() { ...   });
```

instead of building a cycle. Inside the event handlers, use `this` to access the `li` element, and see its `id` if needed.
The event handlers will be assigned to all the `li` elements which are direct children of that `ul` element with `yourid` as the `id`, for example.